# Finding links in file, keeps repeating same link

Tags: python, string

I'm a bit new to Python, but I have taken a HS level Java class. I'm trying to write a Python script that will take all the torrent links in my Humble Bundle downloads page and spit them out into a .txt file. I'm currently trying to get it to read all of them and print them, but I can't seem to get it to look past the first one. I've tried some different loops, and some of them spit it out once, others continuously spit out the same one over and over. Here is my code.

```
f = open("Humble Bundle.htm").read()

pos = f.find('torrents.humblebundle.com') #just to initialize it for the loop
end = f.find('.torrent') #same here

pos1 = f.find('torrents.humblebundle.com') #first time it appears
end1 = f.rfind('.torrent') #last time it appears
while pos >= pos1 and end <= end1:
    pos = f.find('torrents.humblebundle.com')
    end = f.find('.torrent')
    link = f[pos:end+8]#the link in String form
    print(link)
```

I would like help in both my current issue and on how to continue to the final script. This is my first post here, but I've researched what I could before giving up and asking for help. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Parse the HTML with an HTML parser like BeautifulSoup or lxml. Treating the HTML as a string will make this much more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: Even though I have an answer for your question I agree with @Blender. Your solution is quick & dirty, check for better implementations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find more information about `find` method at  http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.find

The problem is when you execute these two lines they always return same value for `pos` and `end` because function always gets same arguments.

```
pos = f.find('torrents.humblebundle.com')
end = f.find('.torrent')
```

`find` method has another optional parameter called start which tells function where to start searching for given string. So if you change your code:

```
pos = f.find('torrents.humblebundle.com', pos+1)
end = f.find('.torrent', end+1)
```

it should work

Comment: This works. Thank you so much. I can't vote it up, but I would.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a regular expression here:

```
import re

f = open('Humble Bundle.htm').read()
pattern = re.compile(r'torrents\.humblebundle\.com.*\.torrent')
print re.findall(pattern, f)
```